# How to rebuild automatically NUnit Tests on creating new Tests or Saving the existing tests

Tags: c#, nunit, nuget-package

I am kind of going through a lot of rebuild every time that i create a new NUnit Test Case (or) update the existing one. Is there a way that i can avoid it. Like, after saving the code, it should auto compile and auto rebuild the code.

I tried to find if there's any Nuget Packages, but may be am still lacking those skills as its been only few days that i started working with .Net stuff

Would appreciate a lot if someone can help on this.

**Note:** aam running the tests within Visual Studio with NUnit 3 Test Adapter

Comment: You haven't said how you are running tests. Is it in VS using the NUnit 3 Test Adapter? [Since you just started, you might not know that there are between 6 and 10 different ways to run NUnit tests, depending how you count them.]

Comment: @Charlie Yes I am for now running my tests from within VS with NUnit 3 Test Adapter.